# Set form fields side-by-side using bootstrap in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails application where i want the form-fields to be side-by-side and not below. The best i can do is get them side-by-side using form-inline but the label gets aligned to the left. The labels should be in the top. I also want to know how to keep the size of the form fields exactly half. My code is:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for '#' do |f|%>
    <div class= "hero-unit">

        <%=f.label "First Name"%>
        <%=f.text_field '#', :class=>"span5" %>

        <%=f.label "Last Name" %>
        <%=f.text_field '#', :class=>"span5" %>
           </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

and this results in:[image: This is the output] but what i require is: [image: This is my requirement]

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Bootstrap [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in order to achieve what you want. Bootstrap has a grid divided in 12 columns. Inputs can, in the same row, be nested, stacked, offsetted, etc. You use the "row" class to create horizontal columns, and predefined grid classes for columns over which you span the content.

In your case, you'll need a row with two grid columns, as such:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for '#' do |f|%>
    <div class="hero-unit">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md6">
          <%=f.label "First Name"%>
          <%=f.text_field '#' %>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md6">
          <%=f.label "Last Name" %>
          <%=f.text_field '#' %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="new">
    <form>
        <div class="new-two"><label>Label name</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…"></div>
        <div class="new-one"><label>Label name</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.new-one {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.new-two {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:40px;
}

.new {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 20px;
 }
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/7V3F7/

Comment: This is not what i want. I want the the text-field to be below the label and another label and text-field to be in the right side. You can see it in the image.